# Loading resources from ResouceDictionary by key with x:Shared="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In WPF library I have a resource dictionary file with some templates, which need to be found by key and used as content of some control:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:DbEditor.Converters"
                x:ClassModifier="internal"
                x:Class="DbEditor.Components.ScalarHandlers"
                >
<Grid x:Key="stringEditor" x:Shared="False">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}"></TextBox>
</Grid>

<Grid x:Key="intEditor" x:Shared="False">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewTextInput="IntTextBox_PreviewTextInput" IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I find one of templates by its key in this way:

```
var scalarDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
scalarDictionary.Source = new Uri("/DbEditor;component/Components/Scalar.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var pair = scalarDictionary.OfType<DictionaryEntry>().FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Key == key);
return pair.Value as FrameworkElement;
```

But added once to some control the element can't be used in another place. In past these templates were stored in App.xaml resources and had attribute x:Shared="False" which made available to use them many times. Now adding x:Shared attribute leads to runtime error

`"Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries."`

I have not found any way to make the resource dictionary be compiled. Changing build action on .xaml file from Page to Resources, Embedded Resources or Compile does not change any.

Is there way to load controls from ResourceDictionary at runtime by key and use them more then once?

Comment: You could try using the control's `Clone` method (inherited from `Freezable`).

Comment: Please use this code.You can find resource keys. Here is code: ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/WpfApplication5;component/Dictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;

Comment: @MikeStrobel, I have not found any control implementing Freezable and may be used as container for controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.freezable(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued

Comment: @MLE loading dictionary in this way leads to the same error - shared attributte cannot be used because dictionary is not compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in a kind of inelegant way. I just created a page, moved resources there and used it in place of ResourceDictionary:

```
<Page x:Class="DbEditor.Components.ScalarPage" ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Grid x:Key="stringEditor" x:Shared="False">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Key="intEditor" x:Shared="False">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewTextInput="IntTextBox_PreviewTextInput" IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>

    ...

    </Page.Resources>    
</Page>
```

and resouce loading:

```
scalarPage = new ScalarPage();               
return scalarPage.FindResource(key) as FrameworkElement;
```

Comment: It looks not cool, so if anyone provides more "WPF" and corrrect answer I will accept it willingly.

Comment: Can you explain what you are using it for? Your current solution seems a bit obtuse and like it could be solved in a much better way, but there isn't enough information to give a proper solution.

Comment: @bonyjoe, in my project I develop property editor for 3.5 framework(I know about wpftoolkit, but it not the thing I need), depending on some paramters like type, name and others I assign a control to a property "Editor" of my property object which used as DataContext of my ObjectPropertiesEditor. This value is used in binding as Content in ContentPresenter control of the editor. So this is why I load these controls at runtime in this way.

Comment: You could instead use the ContentTemplateSelector property on the ContentPresenter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx this will pass the datacontext to a selector that you provide and in the selector you can select and return the correct template. This shows an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Due to plugin based architecture editors cannot be loaded using ContentTemplateSelector: object which stores property title, value, editor, isreadonly and other related data is initialized by cascade  of Filter instances which may be loaded from other dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use DataTemplates in your resource dictionary and set them on the containing controls ContentTemplate property instead of the Content property as I assume you are currently doing so.

You will need to change the code that finds the keys to expect a data template but this will mean you don't need to declare x:shared.

ex

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="stringEditor">
       <Grid>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}"></TextBox>
       </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource stringEditor}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I cannot use `StaticResource` - am loading information about what template to use from database. Also, removing x:Shared attribute even while using DataTempalte container disallows adding loaded element more then once.